# ASp.net Role management in Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web site project using ASp.net Identity 2 authentication.
I can log-in to the site, register new users, run the application pages built so far just fine.
But I need to add Role management, so I can limit functionality by user.
This is proving amazingly difficult to do trying to learn it on your own.
My Asp.net 4.5 book (Murach’s ASP.NET 4.5 Web Programming with C# 2012) says "Use the Web Site Administration Tool"
Which you probably already know, MS has eliminated.
The several methods I have found to try to get to it anyway have failed miserably.

So, I started building my own Admin page for this.
So far it is simple, ugly, and parts of it still don't work. And I just don't know why.

Attached here is my entire Web.config (edited for security), and what is the pertinent code-behind for adding a role. The test code so far will Add a role, and then attempt to assign it to My user ID.

The Role Seems to get created, but I have no idea Where... It does Not end-up in the [dbo].[AspNetRoles] table in my database. I say seems, because when I try again, the test to see if the role exists trips and says it's there already.
            if (!Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName))
            {
                Roles.CreateRole(newRoleName);
            } // End create new role
There is NOT a database in the project Data folder.

System.Web.Providers. is apparently the new, standard Class and 
"it's very likely that these Universal Providers will be the default in the next version of ASP.NET." I hear.
I have the correct DB connection strings assigned.
Clearly there is still Something missing, and I am inheriting some default that I just don't know to look for, somewhere...

Any hints or tips appreciated.
Even a later book.

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Parts-20160425083953.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Parts-20160425083953;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="PartsDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=-redacted-;Initial Catalog=-mydatabasename-;User ID=--dbuserID--;Password=--thepassword--" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="emailServiceUserName" value="--emailuserid--" />
    <add key="emailServicePassword" value="--emailPW--" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<authentication mode="None" />-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="60" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership defaultProvider="ASPNetMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <!--<add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />-->
        <add name="ASPNetMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="PartsDatabase" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="ASPNetProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <!--<add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />-->
        <add name="ASPNetProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="PartsDatabase" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ASPNetRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <!--<add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />-->
        <add name="ASPNetRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="PartsDatabase" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="ASPNetSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <!--<add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />-->
        <add name="ASPNetSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="PartsDatabase" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Code-behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using Sperry_Parts.Models;

namespace Parts.Account
{
    public partial class ManageUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

            gvUsers.DataSource = manager.Users.ToList();
            gvUsers.DataBind();
        }

-- Code-behind for the Add Role button --
        protected void btnAddRole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newRoleName = txtRole.Text.Trim();
            if (!Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName)) 
            {
                Roles.CreateRole(newRoleName); // This works once per new Role - where it Goes is anyone's guess
            } // End create new role


            // Check Users in Roles
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var user = manager.FindByName("myusername");
            string username = user.UserName; // properly returns "myusername"
            if (Membership.GetUser("myusername") != null) // Fails - returns Null
                if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, newRoleName)) // Without the above check, this returns False, I'm not in this role... (natch)
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, newRoleName); // This fails, can't find the user

        } // End Add Role
    }
}
```

That's it
Told you it was just a start...
Editing capability has not been created yet

Answer (score 1):

**web.config** is configured as old ASP.Net Membership Provider.

However, code is the combination of ASP.Net Identity and old ASP.Net Membership Provider.

Please read free [ASP.Net Identity at Apress](http://www.apress.com/files/extra/ASP_NET_Identity_Chapters.pdf) by Adam Freeman.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The samples in that document are also MVC, I see. I don't know anything at all about MVC, so I'm not sure what parts don't apply to Web Forms. There's almost nothing in the sample Web.config that's the same as mine, which was initially built by VS when I created the project. Why it would insert conflicting Identity information I do not know. The only bits I really added were for the Roles provider.

Comment: ASP.Net Identity doesn't use Provider Model which is why you do not see in web.config. Web Site Administration Tool is not able for ASP.Net Identity. If you want to view sample code, you can create a new Web Form Application inside Visual Studio 2015. Logic is pretty much same as Adam Freeman's MVC.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh...... See, this is why sometimes using tutorials can byte you... If they are a little out of date, and they of course don't know that. OK, I need to get my MSDN renewed, The stupid thing expired last week, and our place can be a little Slow to get paperwork in... Then I can get 2015, and start again. :-( I hope the standard built project enables Roles. The New Web Site in 2013 specifically mentioned it was disabled, then directed you to an MVC sample to learn how to enable it.  Sadly, nearly useless for me. MVC is different enough in form and function that I am, not able to translate.

Comment: OK, so, a New project built with 2015 looks exactly like one in 2013. I am just learning now that Membership and Identity are 2 different things. Comments in the VS default config "ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template" lead me to Add the provider code. I still have no clue how to deal with Roles in Identity, but I think I have a clue on what to rip out of the config.